# I have a list of 5 SalesRep that have appointments every day in the morning and afternoon

Tags: sql

I have a list of 5 Sales Reps that have appointments every day in the morning and afternoon.
I want to create a query that list all the other Sales Reps that can replace or covert (other sales rep available for that date and time) booked Sales rep in case emergency.
I work with SQL but I dont know how to do something like this.

My Table looks like this one.

```
Salesrep    Appdate   Category

SalesRep1   4/30/2021   Evening

SalesRep2   4/30/2021   Evening

SalesRep3   4/30/2021   Evening

SalesRep4   5/1/2021    Evening

SalesRep5   5/2/2021    Evening
```

And I want to get something like this

```
Salesrep    AppDate    Category   Replacement

SalesRep1   4/30/2021   Evening   Salesrep4, Salesrep5

SalesRep2   4/30/2021   Evening   Salesrep4, Salesrep5

SalesRep3   4/30/2021   Evening   Salesrep4, Salesrep5

SalesRep4   5/1/2021    Evening   Salesrep1, Salesrep2, Salesrep3, Salesrep5

SalesRep5   5/2/2021    Evening   Salesrep1, Salesrep2, Salesrep4, Salesrep5
```

Comment: What type is AppDate column, is it a date or a varchar?

Comment: Its Date column type!